# Unable to use controller "Error" for 404_override routing

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes, codeigniter-3

I have controller named "Error" in codeigniter "application/controllers/Error.php".

I used this controller to override default 404 error page through routes.

`$route['404_override'] = 'myerror';`

But on 404 error occurrence I am getting following error.

```
 A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'Error' does not have a method 'index'

Filename: core/CodeIgniter.php

Line Number: 514

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\ci-app\index.php
Line: 292
Function: require_once
```

But when I rename Error controller to another, it works.

Please help.

Comment: Change this `$route['404_override'] = 'myerror';` to `$route['404_override'] = 'error';` make sure the class name the same

Comment: yes try with @wolfgang1983 solution .

Answer (score 2):

You need to change your controller and file name to `myerror` like,

```
<?php 
//application/controllers/Myerror.php
class Myerror extends CI_Controller 
{
    public function __construct() 
    {
        parent::__construct(); 
    } 

    public function index() 
    { 
        $this->output->set_status_header('404'); 
        $data['content'] = 'error_404'; // Let View name 
        $this->load->view('index',$data);// loading view
    } 
}
```

Comment: Just info on close tag https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#php-closing-tag